# Find two words occurring before an index in string using python

Tags: python, regex, string

Given text I want to find words occuring before unknown

```
text="the women marathon unknown introduced at the summer olympics los angeles usa and unknown won"  
items=re.finditer('unknown',text).  #as there are 2 unknown
for i in items:  
   print(i.start()) #to get index of 2 unknown
```

output is

```
19 
81
```

Now how to extract words occuring before the two unknowns separately?
For 1st unknown I should get the,women.
and for the second unknown I should get usa,and

Comment: post the expected output

Comment: Do you want use only `re`? It can be done with other methods too.

Comment: Not necessarily re. What are all the other methods?

Comment: I have specified in the question to extract two words before unknown

Comment: Why should you get `the,women` and not `women marathon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short approach:

```
import re

text = "the women marathon unknown introduced at the summer olympics los angeles usa and unknown won"
matches = re.finditer('(\S+\s+){2}(?=unknown)', text)
for m in matches:
   print(m.group())
```

The output:

```
women marathon 
usa and
```

Comment: How to get the "unknown" word also included in this?

Answer (score 1):

This expression might be close to what might be desired here:

```
([\s\S]*?)(\bunknown\b)
```

#### Test with re.findall

```
import re

regex = r"([\s\S]*?)(unknown)"

test_str = "the women marathon unknown introduced at the summer olympics los angeles usa and unknown won"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
```

#### Test with re.finditer

```
import re

regex = r"([\s\S]*?)(unknown)"

test_str = "the women marathon unknown introduced at the summer olympics los angeles usa and unknown won"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sClxKX/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/sClxKX/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Version without `re`, with `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)):

```
from itertools import groupby

text="the women marathon unknown introduced at the summer olympics los angeles usa and unknown won"

for v, g in groupby(text.split(), lambda k: k=='unknown'):
    if v:
        continue
    l = [*g]
    if len(l) > 1:
        print(l[-2:])
```

Prints:

```
['women', 'marathon']
['usa', 'and']
```